# Sub-modules in codeiginter HMVC?

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

I am building a shopping cart system as part of a CodeIgniter 2 site that uses HMVC.

Instead of having one big "cart" module I was hoping I could break up the module into sub modules.

E.g.

```
/modules/cart
/modules/cart/config
/modules/cart/controllers
/modules/cart/models
/modules/cart/views
/modules/cart/modules

/modules/cart/modules/categories
/modules/cart/modules/categories/config
/modules/cart/modules/categories/controllers
/modules/cart/modules/categories/models
/modules/cart/modules/categories/views

/modules/cart/modules/products
/modules/cart/modules/products/config
/modules/cart/modules/products/controllers
/modules/cart/modules/products/models
/modules/cart/modules/products/views
```

Is it possible to do this or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i worked on `codeigniter` before 4-5 months. As per as i remember in application folder we can make `modules`.

Under `modules` package, we can create the package with the name which we required. We may call it as `cart`.

Under `cart`, as per i know, we can not create modules under it. But like each and every folder we can create the particular sub folders and this can solve the your problem as well.

Your folder structure will be like as follows

```
/modules/cart
/modules/cart/config
/modules/cart/controllers
/modules/cart/controllers/categories
/modules/cart/controllers/product
/modules/cart/models
/modules/cart/models/categories
/modules/cart/models/product
/modules/cart/views
/modules/cart/views/categories
/modules/cart/views/product
```

i may we wrong. On this link https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home described very well.